# if $2 \lt x,y\in \Bbb N$ then necessarily $7^{y \cdot 3^{x}} \equiv \pm1 \pmod{27}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

$gcd(27,7)=1$,then: $\phi(27)=18$ and $7^{18} \equiv1\pmod{27}$

so:

$y\cdot3^{x}\pmod{18}\equiv [y\pmod{18}\cdot3^{x}\pmod{18}]\pmod{18}$

$3^{x}\pmod{18}$ for $2 \lt x \in \Bbb N$ is always equlas to 9 (I have proved it using induction)

$[y\pmod{18}\cdot9]\pmod{18}$

How do I continue?

Answer (score 0):

Using that $3^x\equiv9\pmod {18}$ and that $7^{18}\equiv1\pmod{27}$, we have:

$$7^{3^x}\equiv 7^9\equiv (7^3)^3\equiv(-8)^3\equiv 1\pmod {27}$$
And then
$$7^{y3^x}=(7^{3^x})^y\equiv 1\pmod{27}$$

Comment: but $(-8)^{3} \equiv (-26)\equiv 1\pmod{27}$
how do you get $(-1)$ ?

Comment: can explain your answer?
If $y$ is odd...